# What does double dererefence ** do in anchor project?

Tags: anchor, rust, wallet, balance

This is how we write code to add fund to a user in anchor solana project:

```
**user.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()?+=amount;
```

Why is the "**" operator used here?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [signature](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.4.9/solana_sdk/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html#method.try_borrow_mut_lamports) of `try_borrow_mut_lamports()?`, it returns a `RefMut<.., &mut u64)`. The first `*` unwraps `RefMut` and the 2nd one de-references the `&mut` so you can mutate the underlying value.